# Why isn't react passing the state object when using the Link in react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to click a link to the Detailview component. While on the Detailview component/page I need to check the url that the user came from because depending on where they came from will determine the contentthat will show or not..

Im using Link to visit the next page. this is how I have it setup.

```
                <Link to={{
                  pathname: `/Detailview?guid=${curr?.TicketGUID}`,
                  state: {
                    fromPage: '/CompletedTickets'
                  }
                }}>{curr?.TicketID}</Link>
```

but when I console log location on the Detailview page/component I get the following...

```
hash: ""
pathname: "/Detailview"
search: "?guid=dff6c98d-38fe-477e-b13d-03a1a9b0cccd"
state: undefined
```

state is always undefined and the page renders blank, unless I refresh it.
Why is the state value not being defined and/or passed through

do I have the Link set up wrong?

- "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
- "react": "^17.0.2",
- "react-router-dom": "^5.3.1",

EDIT: Adding how I am reading location

right now, im just logging location.

1. I imported useLocation

import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

2. created the location variable

const location = useLocation()

3. I logged it

console.log(location)

Comment: That is how state is passed in the `Link` component in RRDv5, I see no issue with the code. How are you reading the `location` object?

Comment: 1. I imported useLocation
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

2. created the location variable
  const location = useLocation()

3. I logged it
console.log(location)

Comment: We may need to see a running demo that reproduces this issue. Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that we could inspect live?